# Problem with relative reference frames

Tags: aerospace-engineering

I came across this problem a while ago and I'd like to solve it, but I'm not even sure where to start. How would I start this problem and what formulas do I need? I'm not asking for a solution, but that would be awesome. Thanks!

Problem Statement

[image: Problem Statement]

Diagram

[image: Diagram]

Comment: What type of analysis have you done? We require the poster to show sufficient attempt  in solving a problem?

Comment: I haven't really been able to do any analysis yet. I honestly don't know have enough background knowledge to start working on it. I know I need to use the magnetic reference frame to its angular rate of change, then use it to find the orbital rate at the correct angle. I'm not sure how the angle comes into play, why would it effect the orbital rate?